# VBScript - Reading data from excel list

Tags: vbscript, excel.application

I have a couple of questions on reading data from excel sheet using vbscript code and storing 
them in a dictionary object.

1) This is more excel specific. Can I do Data filtering on an excel based on what I select in a master column. For Ex: I have a column name TicketType which has a list of values namely Type1, Type2, Type3. If I select Type1, the data in the remaining columns should show data specific to Type 1, when I select Type2, the remaining columns should change to data specific to Type2.

2) If point one is possible in excel, I would want to use VBScript to select the value first in the master column and then read the filtered data in to a dictionary. I would request for some help here. My whole idea is not to create more rows and instead use one single row and keep filtering and reading.

Thanks
Srinivas

Comment: Do you really mean vbscript (from  a seperate script file) or do you want to use scripting inside Excel - which is `VBA`, not `vbscript`? Apart from that, `write-code-for-me` requests are not answered in this forum. You have to give us code you have written and say where exactly you have difficulties.

Comment: Sorry, I am not asking for code. But would like to know if both the above things are possible or not. If possible, can you give me pointers. I want to know whether VBA books can help me to write this code.

Comment: If that is the case then it not really a question for stackOverflow. We are not here to provide tutorials and answer like  yes that would work. You should just look at AutoFilters.